Is it possible to send images or files via WhatsApp using the url_launcher package in Flutter?
I am trying to send an image along with a message to a specific phone number on WhatsApp using Flutter's url_launcher package. I am currently able to send plain text messages using the whatsapp://send URI scheme, like this:
final whatsappUrl = 'whatsapp://send?phone=91$phoneNumber&text=Hello';
if (await canLaunch(whatsappUrl)) {
  await launch(whatsappUrl);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch WhatsApp';
}

However, I couldn't find any way to include an image in the message using this approach. Is it possible to send images via WhatsApp with url_launcher? If not, is there any workaround or package that allows sending images to WhatsApp in Flutter?"
